# All pages in the network try to load a non-existing Stack Overflow for Teams CSS file

Tags: bug, design, 404-not-found, stack-overflow-for-teams

All pages in the network seem to want to load a non-existing CSS file belonging to Stack Overflow for Teams:

https://stackoverflowteams.com/teams/theme.css?v=:10056:1628160300:11034:1628160300:117442:0

It happens in various browsers (on macOS) so I'm sure it's not one of my userscripts, and in private windows as well. It only happens when I'm logged in, and perhaps only because I'm actually a member of (three) Teams.

[image]

Comment: No repro. Probably it happens only to those who are in a Team? Need more people who are and aren't in a team to verify this theory.

Comment: Also not in a team, and don't see any Teams css file being loaded for me.